# $|f| $ is Lebesgue integrable , does it implies $f$ is also?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $ f $ is Lebesgue integrable then $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable but does the converse of the result is also true?

Comment: Yes -- this follows by definition of integrability (if and only if the absolute value is integrable). Technically a different definition is in force for $|f|$ because it is a non-negative function, but in general $f$ is not.

Comment: You need to assume the measurability of $f$, as some of the answers below point out.

Comment: I agree -- I just thought that $|f|$ measurable implied that $f$ was measurable.

Comment: In hindsight that probably only applies to $f_+$ and $f_-$ -- good save everyone!

Answer (score 7):

No, it does not: If $E$ is (bounded and) non-measurable, then $f = 2\chi_{E} - 1$ is everywhere equal to $\pm1$, so $|f| \equiv 1$, but $f$ is non-measurable, hence not integrable.

Comment: This is a really good counter-example which I (for some reason) had never seen before. I am starring this question so I can remember it.

Comment: I don't understand what means $E$ is non measurable here. is it the difference between Borel measure and Lebesgue measure ? @William

Comment: Well it depends on which sets you accept as measurable. If you are using the Borel sigma algebra, then E would be any non-Borel measurable (but possibly Lebesgue-measurable) set. But if you are using the Lebesgue sigma algebra, then E could only be a non-Lebesgue-measurable set. The distinction usually isn't that outsized when working only with Borel or Lebesgue sigma algebras, but for some applications in probability, for example, we wind up having to consider a far larger number of potential sigma algebras, and hence judge measurability according to the context.

Comment: I like the counterexample because it shows that you can always make a measurable function (since any constant function is measurable even in the trivial sigma algebra consisting of the empty set and the space itself, hence in any other sigma algebra, since they must be larger) from a non-measurable function by taking the absolute value.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f$ to be measurable.

$f$ is bounded by $|f|$ and so it is $L^1$, and hence Lebesgue integrable.

On the other hand, $f$ is lebesgue iff $\int_{X}f^+ \, d\mu<\infty$ and $\int_{X}f^- \, d\mu<\infty$, but we know that $|f|=|f^+ + f^-| \leq |f^+|+|f^-|$ and so $|f|$ is integrable if $|f|$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Think of |f| as a division of f into two functions: $f_+$ and $f_-$.

$f_+$ we define as equal to f on the domain {x: f(x) is non-negative}, and 0 on all other x.

$f_-$ we define as equal to -f on the domain {x: f(x) is negative} and 0 elsewhere. $|f|=f_+ + f_-$.

If |f| is finite, then necessarily both $f_+$ and $f_-$ are finite.